# Access blob by URI using Storage Connection String in C# SDK

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the Azure.Storage.Blobs SDK version 12.7 in C# with .net core and I want to access a blob directly by it's URI using the blob storage connection string for deletion.

How would I do that?
I assume I can use the `BlobClient` class, which constructor takes the URI, but then im not authorized. The constructor takes also a `StorageSharedKeyCredential`, but how can I create it from the connection string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create `StorageSharedKeyCredential` in this way. Note that it uses [the key instead of the connection string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-keys-manage?tabs=azure-portal#view-account-access-keys):

```
StorageSharedKeyCredential storageSharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(<your-account-name>,<your-account-key>)
```

You can refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.storagesharedkeycredential.-ctor?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_StorageSharedKeyCredential__ctor_System_String_System_String_).

By the way, if you want to use connection string, you can use this way:

```
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);

BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(<you-container-name>)

BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
```

Please refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#create-a-container).

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to get account-name and account-key from the connection string?

I don't want to use the BlobContainerClient because I need to access the Blob directly by it's URI ;-). In my case I don't have the container name, only the Blob URI.

Comment: You can get the key and value from the connection string, just parse the connection string. The connection string is in this format: `DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<your-account-key>;AccountKey=<your-account-key>;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net`

Comment: For those following along with Node.JS, you can't use a connection string like so `new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);`. You have to use `BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(connectionString);`